# CSS - Background-clip property 'Mismatched property value'

Tags: html, css

I am attempting to gain inset shadow inside of text.

I followed **[this tutorial](https://mayvendev.com/blog/inner-shadows-in-css-images-text-and-beyond)**, but upon using the `background-clip` attribute in my CSS I received an error:

> Mismatched property value (#|[initial | inherit | unset | revert] This inspection detects illegal property's values

[image]

Is there something I am doing wrong? This seems to be the only thing that is stopping me from getting the appearance I am wanting.

Comment: @RachelGallen - novruzrhmv below managed to help me out by suggesting using `-webkit-background-clip:text;`. Thanks for the advice on the meaning of the error :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use

```
-webkit-background-clip:text;
```